# Power Query - Add a custom column with the file name as the data in the column?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I would like to add the name of the source file as a value for each row in a new custom column in Power Query as the file name as relevant unique identifiers.  Is this possible? I have been through all the functions in the custom column formula but I can't find one that has the path of the source returned.  The path is just a local windows folder and file name.  Ideally I just need the file name but the full path would work too. Thanks!

I have tried to add this code:

#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type1", "Filename", each ????) but can't find a value that will return the filename where the ??? are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to explain better, but on the off chance this helps

Normal code might look like this reading in a file

```
let Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("Z:\Temp\list.xlsx"), null, true),
FPT_Sheet = Source{[Item="FPT",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(FPT_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true])
in #"Promoted Headers"
```

you could change it to look like this

```
let filename="Z:\Temp\list.xlsx",
Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(filename), null, true),
FPT_Sheet = Source{[Item="FPT",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(FPT_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Promoted Headers", "filename", each filename)
in #"Added Custom"
```

perhaps your alternate question is you are reading a range, and want to know the filename of the source range?

create a cell in the file with formula

```
=MID(CELL("filename"),SEARCH("[",CELL("filename"))+1,SEARCH("]",CELL("filename"))-SEARCH("[",CELL("filename"))-1)
```

and give the cell a range name like **filename**

read that into powerquery with

```
filenamehere = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="filename"]}[Content]{0}[Column1]
```

then add a custom column with formula

```
= filenamehere
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I think your first suggestion is close. I added this line:

#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Promoted Headers", "filename", each filename)

But i get the Error: "Expression.Error: The name 'filename' wasn't recognized. Make sure it's spelled correctly"

Comment: Please re-read the instructions clearly showing two methods of creating filename

Comment: To add a bit more color, I am reading in a file, let's say, "C:\My Data\221202 Region001.CSV", my new column would show "221202 Region001.CSV" for the value in each row.

Comment: You are right, I missed the first line and was only looking at the AddColumn line.  If I add the filename = .... line at the top would this now hardcode the path and any novice user wouldn't be able to select the new file to import from the file picker?

Comment: Omg, I love this kind of dialogs ...

Comment: There's a file picker? How do you make a file picker in powerquery?

Comment: Sorry, I probably haven't explained this well.  I want to be able to hand this over to someone to run in future without having to modify the script manually. By 'File Picker' I mean't they can click the cog next to the Source step and select using that rather and updating the path in the script.  But I guess, in short, the question is 'is there a function that returns the source path or filename'

Comment: no there is no function that returns the source path or filename unless that is in a named range in the current file, or you are reading an external file

Comment: Ok, thanks!  Appreciate your feedback.So plan B, use a PQ to show the contents of the import folder in Excel and then loop through that table in Excel and run a PQ against each of those files in that folder from Excel using the path as a variable passed to PQ.... I will have a Google and see what the best options are.